# Bootstrap modal doesn't open in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a hello world - angular(v1.4.9 ) with ui bootstrap(bootstrap-tpls versioned 1.2.5) modal box code written in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b8g4LL1/10/).

On chrome, when i click `Open Me` button, it throws error:

> Error while parsing the 'sandbox' attribute: 'allow-modals' is an invalid sandbox flag.

On firefox, neither the modal opens nor there is any error message.

I ran the same code on my local machine, it throws error:

> Unknown provider: $modalProvider`.

How can i fix the code to open a modal box?

Comment: Violating the code-in-question requirement aside, what exactly do you want us to fix?

Comment: Your code is very confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't work for several reasons ... no `ng-app` and the code is wrapped in the default `onload` in the javascript settings menu.

Once you fix that you need to use more current `$uibModal` service as per the docs:

```
skAngApp.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html'
    });

})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6b8g4LL1/19/)**</kbd>